# Documentation for Maximo API is unreachable?

Tags: api, websphere, documentation, maximo

I am not a 100% sure if this topic is "off-topic" but I couldn't find a more suitable stackexchange for my question.

I am working with the Maximo API and use the IBM docs regularly to help me program. 2 days ago I could still reach the docs such as:

[image]

This gave me a overview of the classes, fields, methods etc.

Today I tried reaching the following docs:

[image]

But the following message shows up:

[image]

Now, I can't possibly believe they have deleted all docs so I assume they might have moved them but I just cannot find them. I tried the search function on the IBM website but no results show up.

Does anyone know where they could have moved them?

PS: If this is off-topic for stackoverflow, could a moderator move the topic to a more appropiate exchange? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IBM Knowledge Center: ibmkc@us.ibm.com

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/overview-summary.html and also the JavaDocs can be downloaded at https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javadocs-maximo-asset-management-76

Comment: If you download the JavaDocs zip file, Windows' default compression utilities will tell you the file is "empty". You will need 7zip or other utility to open it.

Answer (score 1):

The Maximo api or JavaDocs can be accessed and searched using tools such as [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) (for iOS / MacOS) and [Velocity](https://velocity.silverlakesoftware.com) (for MS Windows).

You can also download a copy from IBM for use locally from [IBM Maximo JavaDocs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/javadocs-maximo-asset-management-76)

Hopefully once IBM finishes updating its website the JavaDocs will be available there again for reference online.

[image: IBM Maximo JavaDocs in Dash]
[image: IBM Maximo JavaDocs search in Dash]
[image: IBM Maximo JavaDocs view in Dash]

Answer (score 1):

I have just published the [Maximo 7.6 JavaDocs](https://bportaluri.com/wp-content/MaximoJavaDocs76/) on my blog so they are easily accessible and searched from Google.